# Mapping the value of a json array using filter, groupby and orderby

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have my json in the below format

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "role": {
      "id": "25",
    },
    "target": {
      "id": "1083",
    },
    "staff": {
      "name: "
      ccc "
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "role": {
      "id": "25",
    },
    "target": {
      "id": "1083",
    },
    "staff": {
      "name: "
      aaa "
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "role": {
      "id": "25",
    },
    "target": {
      "id": "1084",
    },
    "staff": {
      "name: "
      staff1 "
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "role": {
      "id": "3",
    },
    "target": {
      "id": "1083",
    },
    "staff": {
      "name: "
      aaa "
    }
  }
]
```

I am trying to group by role id for all specific target ids.Everything works fine except I wanted to also sort the contents by staff name.

```
const groupIt = targetId =>
  chain(data[2])
  .filter(x => x.target.id === targetId)
  .groupBy("role.id")
  .value()

console.log(groupIt('1083'))
```

Expected result

```
{
  "25": [{
      "id": 2 "role": {
        "id": "25",
      },
      "target": {
        "id": "1083",
      },
      "staff": {
        "name": "aaa"
      }

    },
    {
      "id": 2 "role": {
        "id": "25",
      },
      "target": {
        "id": "1083",
      },
      "staff": {
        "name": "ccc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "3": [{
    "id": 4,
    "role": {
      "id": "3",
    },
    "target": {
      "id": "1083",
    },
    "staff": {
      "name": "staff1"
    }
  }]
}
```

I tried keeping orderBy also along with it but it didn't work. I am thinking of looping through each role and sort them. But I am thinking if there is any other solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can orderBy and then group the items. This will set the order inside the groups. However, it won't effect the order of the groups, since the `role.id` is a [numeric property that can be converted to an integer](http://2ality.com/2015/10/property-traversal-order-es6.html).

```js
const data = [{"id":1,"role":{"id":"25"},"target":{"id":"1083"},"staff":{"name":"ccc"}},{"id":2,"role":{"id":"25"},"target":{"id":"1083"},"staff":{"name":"aaa"}},{"id":3,"role":{"id":"25"},"target":{"id":"1084"},"staff":{"name":"staff1"}},{"id":4,"role":{"id":"3"},"target":{"id":"1083"},"staff":{"name":"aaa"}}]

const groupIt = targetId =>
  _(data)
  .filter(['target.id', targetId])
  .orderBy('staff.name')
  .groupBy('role.id')
  .value()

console.log(groupIt('1083'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Droi Thanks. Is there a way that I can orderby staff.name with case insensitive.

Comment: You can use a function and return `staff.name.toLowerCase()`

Comment: Droi I didn't get that exactly. Should I have to use the function in the above logic?

Comment: `.orderBy(o => o.staff.name.toLowerCase())`